# WPF DataGrid - bind Row Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, header, row

I have ObservableCollection with row header names. And I should bind it to my dataGrid.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> criteriasName { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    ...

    //define row heading name
    criteriasName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCriteria; i++)
        criteriasName.Add(criteriaBundle[0].criterias[i].Title);
        ....
}
```

Could you please prompt me how can I bind it to Row Headers?

```
<DataGrid Name="grCriteria" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" CellEditEnding="grCriteria_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding criteriasName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Its strange idea. Can you explain what you want in general?

Comment: @galakt For example I have grid with 4 rows and I have List<string> names = {"first", "second", "third", "forth"}. How can I bind these string values to Row Headers?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have missed the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`. So add it like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="grCriteria" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Then change `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.criteriasName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Also you should chane `DataContext = this;` to `DataContext = criteriasName;` and place it after the `for` loop.